# useLocation from 'react-router-dom' returns unexpected object

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom, yarnpkg, window.location

Note: I'm trying to switch to Plug'n'Play using yarn.

useLocation is imported from 'react-router-dom' package.

Previously (before pnp settings) the line below:

```
const location = useLocation()
```

always returned a location object with the next structure (e.g):

```
{pathname: '/', search: '', hash: '', state: null, key: 'default'}
```

With current yarn pnp settings, build renders app when on the first render, there is a location object with the structure as above, but when trying to change path, there is an object with the next structure (e.g.):

```
{action: 'PUSH', location: {pathname: '/new-path', search: '', hash: '', state: null, key: 'default'}}
```

Why is it so, and how to fix it (to always have a location object returned by useLocation hook of the same structure)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Resolved.**

The issue was that history package was upgraded to v.5.x. At the same time react-router is set to v.^5.2.1. So, the history v.5 is incompatible with react-router v.5.

Looks like history v.5.x is intended for coming react-router v.6.

Downgrading history to v.4 resolved the issue.

*Note: the issue has nothing to do with switching to yarn Plug'n'Play.*